# Why is the Zabbix Agent attempting to connect to PostgreSQL using the 'zabbix' user on certain 'zabbix' DB?

Tags: postgresql, monitoring, zabbix

I'm monitoring my PostgreSQL cluster with Zabbix, and I have a specific username and password for this purpose, which is working perfectly. However, I'm encountering an issue where there is a connection attempt every minute from the Zabbix agent, trying to connect to the database using a 'zabbix' user in the 'zabbix' database. What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Postgres 9.3
zabbix_agent 6

Message on Postgres log

> user=zabbix,db=zabbix,app=[unknown],host=127.0.0.1 LOG:  connection authorized: user=zabbix database=zabbix
> user=zabbix,db=zabbix,app=[unknown],host=127.0.0.1 FATAL:  role "zabbix" does not exist

Comment: Someone may have started to setup the postgres monitor - https://www.zabbix.com/integrations/postgresql

Comment: What authentication method is your pg_hba set to use?

Comment: Please present your log snippet in a way that preserves new lines.  Also, you should probably include a few more surrounding lines of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the use of 'pg_isready' by Zabbix-agent. Zabbix monitors PostgreSQL using a `UserParameter` configuration, and when using `pg_isready` with the Zabbix Linux user, it doesn't specify the user and database, so it defaults to the logged-in user and database names for the connection attempt. This is why you see the `zabbix` user and the `zabbix` database in the connection attempts in your PostgreSQL logs.
To rectify this, you can modify the file `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/template_db_postgresql.conf` line as follows :

```
UserParameter=pgsql.ping[*], pg_isready -h "$1" -p "$2" -U your_username -d your_database_name
```